# eclipse on linux homedirectory added to opening URL

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, kde-plasma

i have a very strange problem with eclipse on a custom ubuntu version from our Client.

Whenever an URL is opened from eclipse this URL is modified and no longer valid.

For example if i klick on the Link https://www.eclipse.org in the eclipse about dialog then my browser opens the following URL:
/home/limux/Downloads/eclipse/https:/www.eclipse.org
instead of https://www.eclipse.org

This issue exists only within eclipse. URLs from the KDE about dialog or gimp work fine.

Details of the environment
custom ubuntu based on version 12.4
desktop kde 4.12.0
eclipse 4.5.1 32Bit and 4.5.0 32Bit

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved.

Solution was to set the Browser to external and check 'Firefox' in eclipse preferences.